# batch file to copy only newly created or modified folders

Tags: xcopy

I want to create a batch file which will copy only newly created folders.I am using the following code but with this it is picking only files(text file or xml files) not the folder.

```
xcopy "D:\Splunk\var\lib\splunk\defaultdb\db"  "D:\test\Incremental_data_backup\"  /m
```

Please suggest what I am missing

Thanks
Vikas

Comment: So do you want only to create empty folders or do you want the folders and any files they might contain? Also do you want the files you copy to be newer than the files in the destination, or do you want them to be newer than a given date?

Comment: as I want to schedule this batch file daily at 10 PM .So what it should do check the source folder and copy only those which are created today only.Similarly when scheduler run this bacth next day it will check if source has a new folder ....I hope I make myself clear ...

Answer (score 4):

You can use xcopy for that, just need to specify the correct options. Here is which ones are relevant to you:

> **/H**           Copy hidden and system files and folders (default=N)
>
> **/D:mm-dd-yyyy**
> Copy files changed on or after the specified date.
> If no date is given, copy only files whose
> source date/time is newer than the destination time.
>
> **/S**           Copy folders and subfolders
>
> **/E**           Copy folders and subfolders, including Empty folders.
> May be used to modify /T.

So something along the lines of:

```
xcopy <src> <dest> /HE /D:mm-dd-yyyy
```

Scripting the date is a bit more complicated:

%date:~4,2% - month
%date:-4% - year
%date:~7,2% - day

So the current date will be:

```
%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%-%date:-4%
```

Comment: I had to use /D:%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%-%date:~10,4% to get this to work on my US Windows 2016 Server.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this code. I use a parameter to mark as a modified folder

```
REM set up the TODAY variable
REM -----
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /T') do set year=%%c
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /T') do set month=%%b
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /T') do set day=%%a
set TODAY=%year%%month%%day%
REM -----

:: yesterdays date
@echo off
set day=-1
echo >"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" s=DateAdd("d",%day%,now) : d=weekday(s)
echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" WScript.Echo year(s)^& right(100+month(s),2)^& 
right(100+day(s),2)
for /f %%a in ('cscript /nologo "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"') do set "result=%%a"
del "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"
set "YY=%result:~2,2%"
set "MM=%result:~4,2%"
set "DD=%result:~6,2%"
set "data=%mm%-%dd%-%yy%"

xcopy D:\YourFolder D:\BAK\BAK_%TODAY% /S /D:%data%  /C /R /I /K /Y
```

Comment: /C /R /I /K /Y :)